# What does a join with multiple ON's mean?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I found a view in one of our databases that has multiple `ON` statements after a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. I didn't know this was valid TSQL and I'm even more confused as to what it means?

Comment: It means that you want to join the tables on rows that meet more than just one condition

Comment: You mean `join table on cond1 and cod2 and cond3` and not `join table on cond1 on cod2 on cond3` which would be invalid

Comment: @juergend not it really says `ON`, `....LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 t3 ON t3.Id = t2.Id ON t1.Type = t4.Type`.

Comment: @Peter So, there should be another join on that view that doesn't have the `ON` conditions. It's weird, but it can be done

Comment: Perhaps if you share the View definition it might help?

Comment: Take a look at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/304c19e6-158c-4b08-b660-9bba56460a8f/understanding-nested-join-syntax?forum=transactsql

Comment: Each `ON` clause is matched to the nearest preceding `JOIN` clause that hasn't already been matched with an `ON` clause. Scan further up the query and you'll find (at least) one `JOIN` clause which hasn't yet been matched.

Comment: @Elliveny if i share the View definition your head would explode!

Comment: @Peter - Ha ha. Looking forward to that then!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ON clauses in FROM force order of joins.

If in expression like this

```
A LEFT JOIN B on A.id = B.id JOIN C on b.id = c.id
```

you'd like to do B INNER JOIN C first, and OUTER JOIN then, you can use parentheses

```
A LEFT JOIN (B JOIN C on b.id = c.id) on A.id = B.id
```

parentheses are not required, you can write ON one after another

```
A LEFT JOIN B JOIN C on b.id = c.id on A.id = B.id
```

ON clauses should be in chiatric relation (first-last, second - one before last etc.)

It is like `2 + 2 * 2`. If expected result is `8`, you have to write `(2 + 2) *2` or use reverse Polish notation to avoid ambiguity, `2 2 + 2 *`. Parentheses are much easier to understand by human but used rarely. When I see several ON in a row without parentheses, usually it is automatically-generated code.

Answer (score 3):

There is only one `ON` clasue of each `JOIN`. 
You might observe multiple ON clauses when you are joining a Table with result of subsequent `JOIN`.

Select statements in below code will give you same result.

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
(
    ID int, 
    Name VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO #Table1
VALUES 
(1, 'ABC'),
(2, 'PQR')

CREATE TABLE #Table2
(
    ID int, 
    Address VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO #Table2
VALUES 
(1, 'Addr1'),
(2, 'Addr2')


CREATE TABLE #Table3
(
    ID int, 
    Dept VARCHAR(5)
)

INSERT INTO #Table3
VALUES 
(1, 'Dept1'),
(2, 'Dept2')

SELECT T2.ID,T1.Name,T2.Address,T3.Dept
FROM #Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN #Table2 T2 ON T1.ID=T2.ID
LEFT JOIN #Table3 T3 ON T1.ID=T3.ID
```

> ```
> SELECT T2.ID,T1.Name,T2.Address,T3.Dept
> FROM #Table1 T1
> LEFT JOIN #Table2 T2 
> LEFT JOIN #Table3 T3 ON T2.ID=T3.ID ON T1.ID=T2.ID
> ```

```
DROP TABLE #Table1,#Table2,#Table3
```

Note: In second select statement, one can not use `ON T1.ID=T3.ID` in place of `ON T2.ID=T3.ID`. This because, Table1 is not directly joined with Table2/Table3 but with result of their join.

Thanks,

Swapnil